# regex for validation attribute to count certain amount of digits in string c#

Tags: c#, regex

i cannot figure the right regex in c# for counting the certain amount for digits exluding other characters but *. for example
no more then 10 digits

```
    1234567890***** - true 
    12**3456**7890 - true 
    12345678901**** - false
...
```

any help? please:)

Comment: You get help on SO only if you help yourself. Please share the code you have written for this and tell us what issue you are facing with that code

Comment: Why not just substitute non-digit characters `\D` with nothing and get the string's length?

Comment: i need regex for validation on attribute, for example  [RegularExpression('')]

Comment: \D won't work because * can be included

Answer (score 4):

You can try *Linq* instead of Regex:

```
using System.Linq;

...

string source = "12**3456**7890";

bool result = source.Count(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9') <= 10;
```

Tests:

```
string[] source = new string[] {
  "1234567890*****",
  "12**3456**7890",
  "12345678901",
};

var tests = source
  .Select(item => $"{item,-15} - {item.Count(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9') <= 10}");

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests));
```

Outcome:

```
1234567890***** - True
12**3456**7890  - True
12345678901     - False
```

Comment: a don't need linq, sorry

Comment: What do you mean you don't *need* Linq? You definitely don't *need* regex. This is the more appropriate approach IMO.

Comment: i need regex for validation on attribute, for example [RegularExpression('')]

Comment: When validating why not using `CustomValidationAttribute`? Just provide `Method` (based on *Linq*) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute.method(v=vs.110).aspx